# Use OleDbDataAdapter to insert into an Access db

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I would like to insert some data into an Access Database.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} where 1=0; ", tmap.SqlTableName);
string con = string.Format(conn, accessPath);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
da.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true); // Returns "INSERT INTO test (int, bdate, amt, text, bit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
da.Fill(dt);
//Add data to the DateTable
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
//....
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
da.Update(dt); //This is where things go south.
```

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
Message:   Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
Source:   Microsoft JET Database Engine.

If I change the insert command:

```
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO test ([text]) VALUES (?)");
```

and change the incoming data to only have a single text value I get:

No value given for one or more required parameters.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't da.Update(dt) be inside the FOR loop, i.e., inside the {}?

Comment: Moving the da.Update(dt) in side the FOR loop would just create new connection to the database every time I added a row, right? -- Anyway moving it doesn't help with the major issue.

Comment: You opened your connection outside the loop, so I don't know why the update would create a new connection. Of course, you're using a technology (oledbdataadapter) that I don't know anything about. In the usual data access libraries used with Jet/ACE, you have to update each row individually, i.e., you can't batch the updates. But maybe what you're using works differently and batches by default. And maybe that's the way it usually works with a server back end and doesn't perhaps work with Jet/ACE. I'm just guessing here.

Comment: @David W. Fenton -- the issue was in the data type. I ended up rolling my own command builder to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the data types. The code in the question works if the data types are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all required columns are included in the insert query.
2. If It doesn't work then create a new method for inserting and follow this:

   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (connectionString);

   ```
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
   command.Connection = conn;
   command.CommandText= "INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2) VALUES (@p_col1, @p_col2)";
   command.Parameters.Add ("@p_col1", OleDbType.String).Value = textBox1.Text;
   ...
   command.ExecuteNonQUery();
   ```

Comment: 1. I removed all the columns from the db except for text. No dice.
2. That is what I was doing before... but there is over 150 tables in the access db and they will change. So I was looking for the easy way to be as dynamic as possible. The command builder looked like a good automagical fit. But it doesn't seem to work for inserting. It looks like I will have to roll my own sql builder for this one.